# How to sub class custom view controller in swift?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I have custom view controller which contains TableView. I have another view controller which extends custom view controller.

How can I pass the TableView from subclass to super view?

Here is the parent view controller:

```
class CustomViewController: CustomNavigationController, UISearchResultsUpdating,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
var query: String = "male"

var tableView: UITableView!

convenience init(tableView: UITableView, query: String){
    self.init()
    self.tableView = tableView
    self.query = query
}
```

And this is what I did in sub class:

```
class GirlsViewController: CustomViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var tableViewObj: UITableView!

convenience init() {
    self.init(nibName:nil, bundle:nil)
}
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    tableView = tableViewObj
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

}
```

The application crash at this line `fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")`

Comment: _You_ are saying `fatalError`. That means crash! You cannot really complain if you crash. The app did _exactly what you told it to do._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do what the error message says: You need to implement `init?(coder`.

The basic implementation is to call `super` and do the same things as in `init(nibName`

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    tableView = tableViewObj
}
```